# Need advice on complex insert scenario using LinqToSql with repository pattern

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, repository, repository-pattern

I have a `User` table and a `ClubMember` table in my database. There is a one-to-one mapping between users and club members, so every time I insert a `ClubMember`, I need to insert a `User` first. This is implemented with a foreign key on `ClubMember` (`UserId REFERENCES User (Id)`).

Over in my ASP.NET MVC app, I'm using LinqToSql and the Repository Pattern to handle my persistence logic. The way I currently have this implemented, my `User` and `ClubMember` transactions are handled by separate repository classes, each of which uses its own `DataContext` instance.

This works fine if there are no database errors, but I'm concerned that I'll be left with orphaned `User` records if any `ClubMember` insertions fail.

To solve this, I'm considering switching to a single `DataContext`, which I could load up with both inserts then call `DataContext.SubmitChanges()` only once. The problem with this, however, is that the `Id` for `User` is not assigned until the `User` is inserted into the database, and I can't insert a `ClubMember` until I know the `UserId`.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to insert the `User` into the database, obtain the `Id`, then insert the `ClubMember`, all as a single transaction (which can be rolled back if anything goes wrong with any part of the transaction)? If yes, how?
2. If not, is my only recourse to manually delete any orphaned `User` records that get created? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` to perform this all in an atomic transaction, but if you are using different `DataContext` instances, it will result in a distributed transaction, which is probably not what you really want.

By the sounds of it, you're not really implementing the repository pattern correctly.  A repository should not create its own `DataContext` (or connection object, or anything else) - these dependencies should be passed in via a constructor or public property.  If you do this, you'll have no problem sharing the `DataContext`:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private MyDataContext context;

    public UserRepository(MyDataContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Save(User user) { ... }
}
```

Use the same pattern for `ClubMemberRepository` (or whatever you call it), and this becomes trivial:

```
using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
{
    UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository(context);
    userRep.Save(user);
    ClubMemberRepository memberRep = new ClubMemberRepository(context);
    memberRep.Save(member);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Of course, even *this* is a little bit iffy.  If you have a foreign key in your database, then you shouldn't even need two repositories, because Linq to SQL manages the relationship.  The code to create should simply look like this:

```
using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
{
    User user = new User();
    user.Name = "Bob";
    user.ClubMember = new ClubMember();
    user.ClubMember.Club = "Studio 54";

    UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository(context);
    userRep.Save(user);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Don't fiddle with multiple repositories - let Linq to SQL handle the relationship for you, that's what ORMs are for.

Comment: Aaron, great answer, thanks. I'm kicking myself because I originally had something similar to your third code snippet, but in the course of debugging, I came to the (incorrect) conclusion that it wasn't going to work. Trying it again now, it works great. Second, my repository classes are based on NerdDinner, so I'm blaming Scott Gu for my less than stellar implementation :). I actually have a "todo" to start wrapping my `DataContext` instances with `using ()` statements, though, and your example gives me a good idea of how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in a single transaction.  Use the TransactionScope object to begin and commit the transaction (and rollback if there is an error of course)